# Alsa library read normalize value

Tags: c++, alsa

I am reading sound value with alsa library. But this values not normalized. Can we read normalize value with this library? I am reading like this with 116bit little endian snd_pcm_readi(capture_handle,buffer,frame));

Comment: What do you mean with "normalized"?

Comment: Normalize mean read value to be -1 between +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get floating-point values between -1 and 1 by configuring the device for a sample format like `SND_PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT`.

Comment: I configure sample format SND_PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT and read. Values came between -1 to 1. But now, after sound values one frame read, the program unexpectedly finish. I am reading value say before.